# How Do I Present a Music Library With a View Controller for a MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate using Swift 3 iOS10?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, presentviewcontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I am trying to follow a recent post on using a `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` to present a music selection list.

The tutorial is found at this URL:

http://www.justindoan.com/tutorials/

I am using this code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate  {

    var mediapicker1: MPMediaPickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController.self(mediaTypes:MPMediaType.music)
        mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        mediapicker1 = mediaPicker
        mediaPicker.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(mediapicker1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

However I have found that the:

```
self.presentViewController(mediapicker1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

does not work. Unfortunately, Swift 3's suggested automatic solution does not work either:

```
self.present(mediapicker1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Furthermore, the iOS 10 Beta Release Notes, found at:

[https://www.scribd.com/doc/315770725/IOS-10-Beta-Release-Notes](http://www.scribd.com/doc/315770725/IOS-10-Beta-Release-Notes)

says on page 10 of 18,

> An MPMediaPickerController object may not display as expected.

I have spent a great deal of time looking to solve this issue on my own with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your link is a mirror of beta documentation.  You should always use the official documentation from Apple.  iOS 10 is released and out of beta.

Comment: @George Lee, I recently publish an app on [appstore](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/playmates./id1156484061?mt=8) which present the Music Library With a View Controller for a MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate using Swift 3. Check if you have same requirement, then I can help you in detail(with code as well)

Comment: @pkc456 that would be nice. Could you share the code on this post?

Comment: @GeorgeLee, I have written the working code in [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39788147/988169). I also mention some discrepancies in your code. I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go through the steps:

1. Add 'NSAppleMusicUsageDescription' to your Info.plist for the privacy authority.
2. Make sure your Music app is available in your iPhone. It will not work in the simulator.

Comment: The plist key `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` is not necessary for the code in the question to run properly.

Comment: @JAL In new iOS10, it will be a blank view comes out. Tested in iPhone6 Plus, iOS10.

Comment: This answer is correct. Addition of the NSAppleMusicUsageDescription in the info.plist does allow for the MPMediaPickerDelegate to display the music list. It will bring up a Privacy - Media Library Usage the Type: String, the Value: Yes.

Answer (score 5):

As per our discussion over comments, I recently use the `MPMediaPickerController` in my latest app [named playmates](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/playmates./id1156484061?mt=8). I am sharing the working code with you. I have written the self-explanatory code.

```
import MediaPlayer

class viewControllerName: UIViewController,MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {

//Below is Inaction for picking music from media library
    @IBAction func btnMediaPickerAction(_ sender: UIButton) {        
            let mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController.self(mediaTypes:MPMediaType.music)
            mediaPicker.delegate = self
            mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
            self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

// MPMediaPickerController Delegate methods
    func mediaPickerDidCancel(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("you picked: \(mediaItemCollection)")//This is the picked media item. 
//  If you allow picking multiple media, then mediaItemCollection.items will return array of picked media items(MPMediaItem)
            }
}
```

I found below discripencies in your code:

- use `self.present` not `self.presentViewController`
- No need to create global instance of `mediaPicker`. As in the delegate method you are getting the instance of `MPMediaPickerController`

Comment: This still does not allow me to select a song like it used to allow (brings up a list of songs to select) in iOS10. Unless I am following your instructions incorrectly.

Comment: Add `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` to your Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Add Privacy - Media Library Usage Description in info.plist